# Different versions of libdc1394?

Tags: linux, libraries

I'm working on a project that uses libdc1394 to interface with Point-Grey Firewire cameras. We build the code on Ubuntu 8, Timesys, and Ubuntu 9 primarily. We usually use the package manager for most dependencies on the Ubuntu's, and the Timesys installation seems to be compiled from source.

Now here's the part that confuses me. I can't figure out what version of libdc1394 is on the Timesys installation. Looking at the library files, I can find a file named libdc1394.so.20.0.0. But these are the header files that I have:

```
dc1394_control.h      dc1394_register.h  dc1394_vendor_avt.h
dc1394_conversions.h  dc1394_utils.h
```

They're in a folder named dc1394. From what I see on the Ubuntu 8 package (which is libdc1394 version 1), I only see dc1394_control.h. And it's in a libdc1394 folder.

From what I see on the Ubuntu 9 computer, which uses libdc1394 version 2.2 (that's the version in the repository), I have a dc1394 folder and then an include directory that looks like the copy I find here: https://libdc1394.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/libdc1394/trunk/libdc1394

I can't find anything about a major change between version 2.0 and 2.2. From the sourceforge page, it looks like the 2.0 version is similar to the Ubuntu 9 version.

Any idea why it seems I have 3 different versions of the library? I understand why Ubuntu 8 and Ubuntu 9, but not why the copy that we have installed on Timesys is different.

Once again, I'm decently sure the one on Timesys was compiled from source. I wasn't around when they did that though, so I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ldd` to see the dependencies on the Timesys executable. That'll tell you WHICH ONE it's loading.